# Is head field value or method in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala.

I'm confused the head is method or field value in Scala immutable List.

the List declaration is below.

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends .... {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: A //I think it is field value not a function or method
  def tail: List[A]
```

But intelliJ said it is method.

What is it exactly?

Comment: There is this nice thing called Uniform Access Principle in Scala. Unfortunately, I was not able to google any nice explanation article quickly. But I recommend to check it out.

Answer (score 6):

List is an abstract class, and `def head` here is an abstract method, so both declaration and IJ are correct.

In nonempty instance of a list, namely `::` it is implemented as follows:

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

So, *field* `head` is used to implement *abstract method* `head`. This is legal in Scala: there isn't much difference between `val` and parameterless `def`, and you can change between one and other in a binary compatible way.

In an empty instance of a list, `Nil`, this method is implemented to throw an exception:

```
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  override def head: Nothing =
    throw new NoSuchElementException("head of empty list")
/*...*/
}
```

A field cannot be "throwing an exception", but a method obviously can.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common pattern in Scala used with `trait`s and `abstract class`es: fields can be overridden by `val`s in subclasses:

```
scala> trait A { def foo: String }
defined trait A

scala> class B(val foo: String) extends A
defined class B

scala> new B("hello").foo
res0: String = hello
```

So the answer is for non-throwing concrete implementations, it will be a `val` and will not put anything on the call stack (see [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L583)); for abstract implementations or throwing concrete implementations, it will be a `def`.

Answer (score 2):

As we all know the hierarchy of `scala.collection` in all high-level abstract classes or traits `Traversable` is parent.
But when you say

```
   def head: A //I think it is field value not a function or method
```

I would say `head` is not a field value but a method. 
if you go to `TraversableLike` trait you will find the below implementation.

```
    /** Selects the first element of this $coll.
    *  $orderDependent
    *  @return  the first element of this $coll.
    *  @throws NoSuchElementException if the $coll is empty.
    */
    def head: A = {
    var result: () => A = () => throw new NoSuchElementException
    breakable {
    for (x <- this) {
     result = () => x
     break
     }
    }
    result()
    }
```

So it takes the collection type `List[A]` and check if the element is empty then throws an exception or else `x` which will be `first` element will be a return and loop will be broken.

Hope this helps you.